# How to build your own transport level protocol?

Tags: java, c++, c, tcp, udp

I've been searching google for how to build your own transport level protocol (The third level of TCP/IP) like TCP and UDP. I only found about how to build protocols for the application layer - on top of udp or tcp, but it is not what I am looking for.

I want to build a protocol like udp and tcp and not on top of them.
Is there any way to do it? I already know how the structure of packets should look like and how to program protocols on top of tcp and udp.

In what language? I don't really care, it can be in C/C++, JAVA, C#, even ASM if it has to and so on...

Comment: Your choices are TCP, UDP and ICMP. TCP/IP is built on similar lines to the OSI model (but it's not identical).

Comment: you are off-topic, you are asking for tutorials and urls but this site is for programming help and coding help.

Comment: what platform are you writing it for?

Comment: If you "want to build a protocol like udp and tcp", either you already know them inside out and feel you can better them, or, you want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm using linux. And it is a programming question (I'm asking for programming tutorials...)
I'm just curious about building my own protocol. As a project for something actually.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with Unix/Linux, you can (probably) construct IP sockets using the `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol);` where `protocol` is either 0 or some number which doesn't conflict with any standard protocol number (see the [list of protocol numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)). `SOCK_RAW` is an [optional POSIX functionality](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#RS) but it's pretty common; both Linux and FreeBSD have supported it for quite a while.

Althouch raw IP sockets are intended to be used to implement IP protocols in user space, it is common to require that processes have special privileges in order to open a raw socket. (Otherwise, a non-privileged process would be able to intercept privileged TCP or UDP ports.) In Linux, you'll require `CAP_NET_RAW`; see `man 7 raw` and `man 7 capabilities`.

Implementing a transmission protocol in user space has some advantages, particularly during development, but it may be difficult to reliably implement some timing-related features. Of course, kernel modules are extremely non-portable; a user space implementation of an IP protocol using raw IP sockets will only be somewhat non-portable.

There are some examples of protocol user-space protocol implementations; I don't know of a tutorial (but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist), but Google did find me this [interesting paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/dsg/mpi-sctp/userspace_ICCCN2012.pdf) on a user-space implementation of SCTP, and you can also work through the [Wikipedia article on raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) and its references.